# SWT Label/Text is not shown in Composite

Tags: java, text, swt, label, composite

I'm using SWT to add a `Label` or a `Text` in a `Composite`. But it is never shown and I don't see the mistake in my code. Does anyone have any idea what could be my problem?

This is a simple code snippet:

```
    //some code before...
    shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(1000, 700);
    shell.setText("Window");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));

    Composite contentUp = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    GridData contentUpData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);     
    contentUpData.horizontalSpan = 3;
    contentUpData.heightHint = 100;
    contentUp.setLayoutData(contentUpData);

    final Label label = new Label(contentUp, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Show me");
    label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    //...
    shell.open();
```

Comment: You need set layout on Composite contentUp = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);

Comment: Sounds like this:   

contentUp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));  

right?

Comment: yes.always set layout on Composite.